# How to send multiple images through ajax and receive them through the view model?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Suppose I have this ViewModel

```cs
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public string AlbumDescription { get; set; }
    public List<FormFile> CuteImages { get; set; }
    public List<FormFile> BadImages { get; set; }
}
```

This form

```html
<form id="AlbumForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="AlbumDescription" />
    <input type="file" name="CuteImages" multiple/>
    <input type="file" name="BadImages" multiple/>
    <button type="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

This Javascript

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    let form = document.getElementById("AlbumForm")

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Album/Add",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: new FormData(form)
    });
})
```

And this Album Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(AlbumViewModel viewmodel)
{
    var description       = viewmodel.AlbumDescription; //OK
    var filesFromHeaven   = viewmodel.CuteImages;       //null
    var filesFromHell     = Request.Form.Files;         //OK
    ...
}
```

I can get the images from the request but they appear ***null*** in the ***viewmodel***.

The ***description*** is in the ***viewmodel***, any properties other than the files are loaded.

I need the files to come from the ***viewmodel*** cause then I can use the cool ***data-annotation*** things to validate everything.

Does anyone know what could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change `FormFile` to `IFormFile` in the model like below:

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public string AlbumDescription { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> CuteImages { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> BadImages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It worked, I spent half a day trying to get this done and it was just the interface all this time, thank you so much for the answer.